# Geometry error in roadnetwork

Tags: qgis, postgis, geometry, invalid-data

I have a road network table. When I check `st_isValid(the_geom)='f'`, I am getting an error:

> NOTICE:  IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1
>   elements
>
> ERROR:  Exception in LWGEOM2GEOS

When I open this table in QGIS, I can view and edit the data. However, its attribute table is blank, while in PostGIS, the table has data.

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you try st_makeValid(the_geom)? This function probably will help you. (postgis 2.0 function)

Comment: no I have postgis 1.0

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have postgis 2.0 you can do this: 
-use qgis "check geometry validity function" find the error and correct it manually
OR 
-import your layer in grass using qgis plugin. Grass import tool uses v.clean for cleaning an rebuilding topology, so your layer will be correct automatically. After that you have to load your new grass layer in qgis and re-export it in postgis.